# Circle hole bevel defect

Tags: faces, bevel

When I tried to bevel a square it doesn't give me the perfect circle I wished for.
this is the result:
[image]

and the image below is before beveling:
[image]

Can you help me to solve this problem? Because when I remove the face of the defect it would remove some of the faces below that I did not wish to be removed. Thanks.

Comment: Looks weird, perhaps you have some duplicate vertices? Can you share your .blend file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doubles are one thing, but topology is bad as well. Make it look like the other one and dissolve diagonal edges and their verts on this imperfect circle. These vertices are obsolete. To have a perfect bevel circle you must have exactly four vertices, or a pure square. Also check Clamp Overlap option.
[image]
In the example I used a plane with edges 4m in length.